# Delete with double FROM clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm surprised this works. I'm not sure I understand why.

```
create table #tempt(something int)

DELETE FROM #tempt -- works fine
FROM #tempt EM
```

I'd expect to need to use the alias in the DELETE and I'd especially expect to not need that first `FROM`. Why can that first `FROM` exist?

```
DELETE EM --what I would expect to work
FROM #tempt EM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you look documentation [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> ```
> [ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]
> DELETE 
>     [ TOP (expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
>     [ FROM ] 
>     { { table_alias
>       | <object> 
>       | rowset_function_limited 
>       [ WITH (table_hint_limited [ ...n ] ) ] } 
>       | @table_variable
>     }
>     [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]
>     [ FROM table_source [ ,...n ] ] 
>     [ WHERE { <search_condition> 
>             | { [ CURRENT OF 
>                    { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } 
>                        | cursor_variable_name 
>                    } 
>                 ]
>               }
>             } 
>     ] 
>     [ OPTION ( <Query Hint> [ ,...n ] ) ] 
> [; ]    
> <object> ::=
> { 
>     [ server_name.database_name.schema_name. 
>       | database_name. [ schema_name ] . 
>       | schema_name.
>     ]
>     table_or_view_name 
> }
> ```

There are two `FROM`s!

The first is optional and identifies the target table.

The second (is not standard) and it can be used to achieve extra filtering on the target table with joins instead of exists.

With a little bit of further investigation it seems that the first `FROM` is the standard way of writing the `DELETE FROM` statement. But using the second `FROM` makes the statement look unnatural (like you noted) so this may be the reason behind it being optional.

Comment: actually both are optional, not only the first.

Comment: yeap. The first is optional in the sense that it does not add anything to the statement. You can write DELETE FROM TABLE and you can omit FROM and write DELETE TABLE and still get the same result. On the other hand if you want to use a join you must use the second.

Answer (score 2):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) (excerpt):

```
DELETE 
    [ FROM ] 
    { { table_alias
      | table_or_view_name       
    }
    [ FROM table_source [ ,...n ] ]
```

First `FROM`:

> FROM: An *optional* keyword that can be used between the DELETE
>   keyword and the target *table_or_view_name*

Arguments of first `FROM`:

> *table_alias*: The alias specified in the FROM table_source clause
>   representing the table or view from which the rows are to be deleted.
>
> *table_or view_name*: The name of the table or view from which the rows
>   are to be removed.

Second `FROM`:

> FROM table_source: Specifies an *additional* FROM clause. This
>   Transact-SQL extension to DELETE allows specifying data from
>    and deleting the corresponding rows from the table in
>   the first FROM clause.

So, in just a few words:

- First `FROM` is *optional* and is used to specify the *target* table from which rows are to be deleted. You can omit it, as you point out in the OP, and just use the *table_alias* specified in the 2nd `FROM`.
- Second `FROM` is a T-SQL extension, used to specify the rows to be deleted from *target* table.

Comment: It's clear to me that this is definitely legit but what is not clear is if having the two adds any readability to the statement.